# Setup HTTPS on wildcard subdomain on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, laravel

I have created a `Laravel` application on my local Ubuntu machine. But I want to use `HTTPS` on all of its wild card sub-domains. How can I do this locally? By the way, I have added my site URL on `etc/hosts` so I don't need to type `localhost` but instead `www.mysite.loc`.

Answer in this question [How can I install SSL on localhost in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946170/how-to-install-ssl-on-localhost-in-ubuntu), I think will only work on the main domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the answer with this question [How can I install SSL on localhost in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946170/how-to-install-ssl-on-localhost-in-ubuntu) is working fine. But you need to modify few lines of code in your `conf` file.

I manage to try it now and works fine but I got this irritating message from my browser that the site I am accessing is not secure. Though it's okay, since it is just self signed certificate.

In my `/etc/hosts` I added several sub domains for my local site since it will not work even you configured your virtual host properly because the site your developing is not yet accessible online.

Say, `www.mydomain.com`, `hello.mydomain.com`, `world.mydomain.com`

Now, we need to enable SSL module

`sudo a2enmod ssl`

Restart Apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Create a folder for Self-signed SSL Certificates

`sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl`

Generate key and other stuffs for SSL

`sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt`

Answer questions their and use your domain say `mydomain.com` as `Common name`

Now I edited the `conf` file of my virtual host which resides in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.conf`

This is the what's inside

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/me/projects/www/mysite_folder
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>   

    <Directory "/home/me/projects/www/mysite_folder">
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
       Require all granted
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

If you already enable your virtual host, you need to skip this step. Else, type

`sudo a2ensite mydomain.com.conf`

Lastly, you need to restart Apache again by

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope it helps you! You can now access your site using `https`

Ex. `https://www.mydomain.com`, `https://hello.mydomain.com`, `https://world.mydomain.com`

Comment: Wow, thanks. I need to setup this now. I will accept it later if it will work.